# How can I show my text in just a one line?

Tags: php, mysql, css

I'm getting values from MySQL and I want to show them in a mini line. But because of the line's length they are creating new lines by themselves.

My CSS code below there is;

```
position:absolute;
top:76px;
left:25%;
width:50%;
height:30px;
background-color:#d0d0d0;
```

and my print is;
http://666kb.com/i/c6810lb5lniu28x41.png

I want to show them just in first line that you see.
Thanks.

Comment: by changing the font... font-size:0.3em; for instance

Comment: I want to do that without font change. :/

Comment: do what do you mean by mini line really ?

Comment: that's what you get by changing the font

Comment: do you mean you want to display it on a single line??Can't you increase the width to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `white-space: nowrap;` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, but when i use this I can't see my whole values except the first one.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the [`font-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp), put it in [`<small></small>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font_style.asp) tags, change the [`width`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) or use [`overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)